# How do I split only one element of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am working on a practice coding interview on filtered.ai and am having trouble working with the input. filtered.ai uses for line in inputfile.input()
the first line is my sum variable and the second is what will be turned into an array.

I was able to remove the new line character and get to one list which is a good start. Now I am left with a list `arr  = ['5 ', '1 2 2 3 1']`

```
import fileinput
import sys
arr = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    line = line.replace('\n',' ')

    arr.append(line)
   #sys.stdout.write(line)

print(arr)
```

I would like to have one list to work with where the first value is always the sum value and the second is the list to manipulate/process logic on. 
I would like `arr = [[5],[1,2,2,3,1]]`

Comment: Wouldn't a dictionary like: `{"sum": 5, "values": [1,2,2,3,1]}` be a more suitable data structure?

Comment: Possibly I am not super familiar with using dictionaries in python. I am working on a problem on filtered.ai and really struggling. The problem title is "Degree of array". I am struggling manly with the input portion then the logic.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a list comprehension

```py
arr = [[int(x) for x in string.split()] for string in arr]
```

Returns:

```py
[[5], [1, 2, 2, 3, 1]]
```

Comment: could also be written using `map`: `[list(map(int, string.split())) for string in arr]`

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs are in a file called 'file.txt', then you can use the following:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
  arr = f.read().split('\n')
  nums_sum = int(arr[0])
  nums = map(int, arr[1].split())
  result = [[nums_sum], list(nums)]
```

If the file content is:

```
10
2 2 6
```

Then your result will be:

```
[[10], [2, 2, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be more readable

```
arr  = ['5 ', '1 2 2 3 1']
ans = []
for a in arr:
    a = a.rstrip().split()
    a = [int(x) for x in a]
    ans.append(a)
ans
```